# py.test & pytest on Raspberry Pi : Differences ?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pytest

On my Raspberry Pi model B, py.test and pytest are different
I am new to python and new to the Pi ... 
So any clues welcomed

If I look at the command executed I have 
For py.test:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# EASY-INSTALL-ENTRY-SCRIPT: 'pytest==2.7.2','console_scripts','py.test'
__requires__ = 'pytest==2.7.2'
import sys
from pkg_resources import load_entry_point

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(
        load_entry_point('pytest==2.7.2', 'console_scripts', 'py.test')()
    )
```

for pytest (run as python -m pytest ) :

```
#!/usr/bin/python -u

import warnings
warnings.simplefilter('default', DeprecationWarning)

from logilab.common.pytest import run
run()
```

Can someone explain why those 2 syntaxes ?
Could I use one or the other (and get the same results) ?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

Both tools have nothing to do with each other.  For some unfortunate reason logilab started shipping a binary called `pytest` in their logilab-common package, even thoug at that time the `py.test` testing tool already existed and it's package name already was `pytest`.  And hence the confusion now.

But to clarify: `py.test` the testing tool from pytest.org installs a binary called `py.test` which is contained in the `pytest` python package and uses the `pytest` dstribution name on pypi.python.org.